# Acr.Biometrics Xamarin plugin

Tags: android, uwp, xamarin.forms

I create Xamarin.Forms app and use Acr.Biometrics plugin. In PCL I check available finger print for device.

```
private async void AvailableBiometric()
{
      bool available = await Biometrics.Instance.IsAvailable();
      lblStatus.Text = available ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

When I launch my app on Windows 10 emulator (UWP project), I get result false ("NO") and it's correct. But when I launch app on Android 6.0 (Emulator or real device with finger authorization), I get Exception "".

I find source code this plugis on GitHub. My Exception generate this plugin's code:

[image]

I don't understand what do I wrong and why for Windows app this Exception did not generate. If who know, please, help me.

Comment: Make sure you have the Acr.Biometrics nuget package installed to your Android application project, otherwise the bait-and-switch method used to load the Android-specific implementation will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand what do I wrong and why for Windows app this Exception did not generate.

I tried to only install `Acr.Biometrics` Package to PCL, and debugged `UWP` project. It also threw the exception.

If you want to use lib of `Acr.Biometrics` in Android and UWP platform,
please make sure you have installed [`Acr.Biometrics`](https://github.com/aritchie/biometrics) nuget package to `Android` and `UWP` project.

You can right click your solution--> Manage NuGet Package for solution-->select the `Installed`button-->left click `Acr.Biometrics` NuGet Package.

[image]

Check the xxx.Droid project option.And then press the install button. The installation is done later.

For Android support, you need to add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

**Usage**

In your shared/PCL library, simply check if the sensor is available:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (await Biometrics.Instance.IsAvailable())
    {
        var success = await Biometrics.Instance.Evaluate("Your custom message");
        if (success)
        {
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I installed nuget packages in the both projects and had vy Exception. Then I remove pakages and reinstall them. This is solved my problem.